# Do I need undervoltage protection?

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-operated, attiny

I am making a small, handheld device powered by a 9V battery. I am using this [regulator](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/mcp1702t-5002ecb/microchip-technology) and the [ATtiny104](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATtiny104). My question is, do I need to protect against a low voltage battery? The minimum input for the tiny is 1.8 volts so do I need a device to shut off the power when the 9V hits about 6V (and then rapidly drops voltage) or can the tiny handle such a voltage for the brief amount of time before the circuit turns off when the battery fully discharges. If it helps, I estimate the current draw of the circuit to be about 200-250mA.

Comment: UVP is important when corruption of functions occurs.  But 9V seems like a mismatch for a 5V LDO. with 44% loss in power in the LDO at 9V. Much smarter to use 3.6V LiPo. with UVP at 3V. Especially when drawing 0.25A from a battery with higher ESR.

Comment: I'm trying to keep costs down with this product, 40 cents per LDO with a couple of cheap-ish caps sold me on it. I might make a more expensive one with a usb rechargeable LiPo later.

Comment: cheap but is it good? 1hr to 7V ? 3h to 3V?   9V Alk. Panasonic are rated for only 100mA MAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons for undervoltage protection.

1. To protect the battery from discharging excessively- a condition that can damage rechargeable batteries or cells.
2. To keep the circuit from damaging itself or something that it is controlling, including data integrity in EEPROM, flash etc. This may include ensuring an orderly reset so that it starts up in a valid state when power is restored.

You will not damage the micro itself by applying voltage that is too low. Data corruption will *probably* not be a problem if your program doesn't write to nonvolatile data memory, and you clear the NVM lock bits with in-system programming.

Answer (score 1):

Under-voltage protection is generally not needed, see Tony Stewarts's comment.

However, it also depends on the function of the device. If it controlling something critical you will want it to go into a known "SAFE" state BEFORE the power drops to the point that the micro and other circuitry will no longer reliably function.